# C# Xml attribute values to string variable

Tags: c#, xml

Hey I was wondering if anyone could help to save the value of my xml doc to a c# variable. It is to help with a larger program feature. The XML layout is:

```
<row>
    <var name="bud" value="45" />
    <var name="acc" value="345" />
</row>
<row>
    <var name="bud" value="45" />
    <var name="acc" value="345" />
</row>
```

I would like to extract the value of bud and store it as a string in my c# code

thanks for any help guys I appreciate it.

Comment: You're looking for [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML has to be valid so added a root element.

**XML:**

```
<foo>
 <row>
    <var name="bud" value="45" />
    <var name="acc" value="345" />
 </row>
 <row>
    <var name="bud" value="45" />
    <var name="acc" value="345" />
 </row>
</foo>
```

**Code:**

This will return a List with the values of all variables "var" in your XML named "bud" and finally create a comma separated string with all the values.

```
        string xml = "<foo><row><var name=\"bud\" value=\"45\" /><var name=\"acc\" value=\"345\" /></row><row><var name=\"bud\" value=\"45\" /><var name=\"acc\" value=\"345\" /></row></foo>";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var budValues =(from c in doc.Descendants("var") 
                       where c.Attribute("name").Value == "bud" 
                       select c.Attribute("value").Value).ToList();
        string myBuddy = string.Join(",", budValues);
```

Comment: xml is...well..the xml you want to load, I added it so you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Your xml is not valid. It requires a single root node.

Here is simple solution using [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath):

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(@"
    <dataset><row>
        <var name=""bud"" value=""45"" />
        <var name=""acc"" value=""345"" />
    </row>
    <row>
        <var name=""bud"" value=""45"" />
        <var name=""acc"" value=""345"" />
    </row></dataset>");
XmlNode node = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/dataset/row/var[@name='bud']");
string value = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
```

This gets only the first of the matches where @name='bud'. Checkout [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to adjust your result. (it's pretty powerful)